# Can I use npm custom flags to set the value of a configuration variable usable in webpack.config?

Tags: webpack-2, npm-scripts

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
npm run build --path custom
```

in order to set a different output.path that will be used in webpack.config.js

Does something like this exists?

Comment: I should be able to do something like `npm run-script build  -- --foo="bar"` but I haven't be able to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution used in the end uses this command:

```
DIST=[YOUR-DIRECTORY] npm run build
```

The `webpack.config` handles the value of `DIST` like:

```js
const target = process.env.DIST
  ? process.env.DIST
  : 'dist';
```

and in the output we go with:
`path: path.resolve(__dirname, target)`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve something similar to my goal like using a config field like this:

```json
"name": "foo",
"config": {
  "dist": "bar"
},
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --watch",
  "custom": "node test.js"
}
...
```

I managed to modify the value of `dist ("bar")` with:

```
npm config set foo:dist apple
```

And I can access the value of `dist` with:

```
process.env.npm_package_config_dist
```

Probably not ideal, but it works. I'm open to better suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

You may try this:

```json
"name": "npm-help",
"scripts": {
   "build": **"sass --watch"**,
}
```